# How do I make CSS control my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table similar to [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/P97Pa/) that looks like:

```
<table class="DynaTable">
    <tr class="DynaTableHead">
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-1">col 1</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-2">col 2</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-3">col 3</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-4">col 4</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-5">col 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 1-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 1-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 1-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 1-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 2-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 2-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 2-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 2-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 2-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 3-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 3-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 3-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 3-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 3-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 4-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 4-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 4-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 4-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 4-5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Want I want to do when the user loads the page on a mobile device, make it display like [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/pv7Tj/1/) that looks like:

```
<table class="DynaTable">
    <tr class="DynaTableHead">
        <th rowspan="2" class="DynaTableHeadCell-1">col 1</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-2">col 2</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-3">col 3</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-4">col 4</th>
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-5">col 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableHead">
        <th class="DynaTableHeadCell-X" colspan="3">col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td rowspan="2" class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 1-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 1-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 1-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 1-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-X" colspan="3">cell 1-3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td rowspan="2" class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 2-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 2-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 2-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 2-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 2-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-X" colspan="3">cell 2-3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td rowspan="2" class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 3-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 3-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 3-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 3-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 3-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-X" colspan="4">cell 3-3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="DynaTableRow">
        <td rowspan="2" class="DynaTableRowCell-1">cell 4-1</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-2">cell 4-2</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-3">cell 4-3</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-4">cell 4-4</td>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-5">cell 4-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DynaTableRowCell-X" colspan="3">cell 4-3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make this work using only HTML and CSS?  I "can" use JavaScript/jquery, but I would REALLY rather not.  The output is what is important.  I can go from the first output to the second output when mobile loads it, OR I can go from mobile version to desktop version -- doing the latter would make avoiding JavaScript less important.  Does CSS offer rowspan/colspan options now (it didn't use to last time I tried, but that was 3-5 years ago)?

Comment: You could apply this using CSS media queries.

Answer (score 3):

1- you can style your website by using the fluid method [see this](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

2- you can do it by using media type in CSS [see this](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to maintain HTML without using a server-side scripting language like ASP, CGI or PHP then you cannot avoid using JavaScript. Otherwise you have no means of detecting which device or OS is being used.

Comment: Sorry for answering the question as was specifically asked.

Comment: No problem there as down votes don't bother me. I only use this service to get "answers" like one I posted days ago with a bounty.

Comment: By your comment that they don't bother you, I must assume they really do... I tried to say this from my mobile, but the post failed.  You did not answer the specific question.  Also, it can be done client-side and without JavaScript according to the answer and comment above yours.  Give me a fair description why those wouldn't work, and I will remove the down-vote. :)

Comment: The question asks if it can done without using JavaScript... by just using HTML and CSS. If you are using anything server side then you are not using plain HTML... you will then be using another programming language to create HTML on the fly. For example, you cannot use server-side languages and still have a page named as *.html. So how did I not answer the question most precisely?

Comment: So, you're saying that media type CSS (which I'm leaning towards) and fluid styling of the pages won't work?  I'll still "have" to use PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Correct. Static HTML and CSS on their own cannot detect which device or OS is being used.

Comment: `<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' href='css/iphone.css' />` Won't work? Before you say no, please read: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp  and  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: Such a stylesheet is still static. It doesn't matter if you have several different stylesheets or one stylesheet catering for several different scenarios. Until you can detect what device is requesting the page it doesn't know which CSS or part of the CSS should be used.

Comment: I was under the impression from all of what I'm reading that the browser looks at the link statements, the browser know what it is and what system it is running on, and if it is offer a list of css sheets with the media= it will only load the ones that it qualifies for.

Comment: I doubt it. Naming your CCS stylesheet as "iphone.css" won't do anything.

Comment: It's not the name of the href that does it, the browser sees the `media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'` or even `media='handheld and (max-device-width: 480px)'` and knows whether or not it qualifies.